# How to calculate dissimilarity matrix in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

Is there any function or method that calculates dissimilarity matrix for a given data set? I've found [All-pairs similarity via DIMSUM](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/all-pairs-similarity-via-dimsum) but it looks like it works for sparse data only. Mine is really dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the [original DIMSUM paper](http://stanford.edu/~rezab/papers/dimsum.pdf) is talking about a matrix which:

> each dimension is sparse with at most L nonzeros per row

And which values are:

> the entries of A have been scaled to be in [−1, 1]

This is not a requirement and you can run it on a dense matrix. Actually if you check the sample code by the DIMSUM author from [the databricks blog](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/20/efficient-similarity-algorithm-now-in-spark-twitter.html) you'll notice that the `RowMatrix` is in fact created from an `RDD` of dense vectors:

```
// Load and parse the data file.
val rows = sc.textFile(filename).map { line =>
    val values = line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble)
    Vectors.dense(values)
}
val mat = new RowMatrix(rows)
```

Similarly the comment in `CosineSimilarity` [Spark example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/CosineSimilarity.scala) gives as input a dense matrix which is not scaled.

You need to be aware that the only available method is the `columnSimilarities()`, which calculates similarities between columns. Hence if your input data file is structured in a way record = row, then you will have to do a matrix transpose first and then run the similarity. To answer your question, no there is no `transpose` on `RowMatrix`, other types of matrices in MLlib do have that feature so you'd have to do some transformations first.

[Row similarity is in the works](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4823) and did not make it into the newest Spark 1.5 unfortunately.

As for other options, you would have to implement them yourself. The naive brute force solution which requires `O(mL^2)` shuffles is very easy to implement (cartesian + your similiarity measure of choice) but performs very badly (speaking from experience).

You can also have a look at a different algorithm from the same person called [DISCO](http://stanford.edu/~rezab/papers/disco.pdf) but it's not implemented in Spark (and the paper also assumes L-sparsity).

Finally be advised that both DIMSUM and DISCO are estimates (although extremely good ones).